# Trying to get property of non-object simplexml in PHP

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm trying to get interest rate value from the XML file given in the URL. I would just get the notice saying: "Trying to get the property on a non-object".

Can anyone help me figure this out please?

Here is my code:

```
$url = "http://www.suomenpankki.fi/en/tilastot/korot/Pages/tilastot_markkina-_ja_hallinnolliset_korot_euribor_korot_today_xml_en__XML.aspx?output=XML ";
$eurorate = file_get_contents($url);
$name="rate";
$newFile = 'xml/'.$name."xml";
file_put_contents($newFile,$eurorate);

$interest = @simplexml_load_file($newFile);
$date = $interest->period['value'];
$interest_rate=$interest->rate[14]->intr['value'];
```

XML file:

```
<Report xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns="euribor_korot_today_xml_en" xsi:schemaLocation="euribor_korot_today_xml_en http://inrs1/ReportServer?%2Ftilastot%2Fmarkkina-_ja_hallinnolliset_korot%2Feuribor_korot_today_xml_en&rs%3AFormat=XML&rs%3ASnapshot=2015-10-12T09%3A00%3A20&rc%3ASchema=True" Name="euribor_korot_today_xml_en" title="Euribor rates 09 Oct 2015" description="The Euribor rate is calculated on the rate quoted by prime banks, operating in the euro area. There are approximately 50 banks represented in the arrangement, in Finland's case it is Nordea. The quotation is given at midday, Finnish time. The calculation is made leaving the 15% lowest and highest offers out and by calcualtion the unweighted average. " creator="Bank of Finland" frequency="D" date_format="yyyy-MM-dd" updated="2015-10-12">
<data provider="Reuters">
<period_Collection>
<period value="2015-10-09">
<matrix1_Title_Collection>
<rate name="1 week (act/360)">
<intr value="-0.149"/>
</rate>
<rate name="1 week (act/365)">
<intr value="-0.151"/>
</rate>
<rate name="2 week (act/360)">
<intr value="-0.144"/>
</rate>
<rate name="2 week (act/365)">
<intr value="-0.146"/>
</rate>
<rate name="1 month (act/360)">
<intr value="-0.113"/>
</rate>
<rate name="1 month (act/365)">
<intr value="-0.115"/>
</rate>
<rate name="2 month (act/360)">
<intr value="-0.073"/>
</rate>
<rate name="2 month (act/365)">
<intr value="-0.074"/>
</rate>
<rate name="3 month (act/360)">
<intr value="-0.049"/>
</rate>
<rate name="3 month (act/365)">
<intr value="-0.050"/>
</rate>
<rate name="6 month (act/360)">
<intr value="0.028"/>
</rate>
<rate name="6 month (act/365)">
<intr value="0.028"/>
</rate>
<rate name="9 month (act/360)">
<intr value="0.072"/>
</rate>
<rate name="9 month (act/365)">
<intr value="0.073"/>
</rate>
<rate name="12 month (act/360)">
<intr value="0.139"/>
</rate>
<rate name="12 month (act/365)">
<intr value="0.141"/>
</rate>
</matrix1_Title_Collection>
</period>
</period_Collection>
</data>
</Report>
```

Comment: You're silencing any helpful error messages with `@` before `simplexml_load_file();`. I'm guessing that function is failing. (If you don't know why the `@` is there, you should remove it)

Comment: If I remove it, I get the "Warning: simplexml_load_file(): xml/ratexml:1: namespace warning : xmlns: URI euribor_korot_today_xml_en is not absolute in /var/www/html/md1/index.php on line **".

Comment: more warnings here: "Warning: simplexml_load_file(): i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="euribor_korot_today_xml_en" in /var/www/html/md1/index.php on line 50

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in /var/www/html/md1/index.php on line 50"

Comment: Take a look at the [examples in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php); in particular, note how the `->` operator works and look at where the `period` element in your example is, inside the `data` and `period_Collection` elements.